# Regex For Ophthalmology Refraction

Tags: .net, regex, vb.net

I'm trying to create a regex (.net) that would match a particular data set used in ophthalmology called a refraction. The purpose of this match is to read serial data from a diagnostic device and parse it accordingly. I need to try and account for issues when there is a buffer error or only a partial reading has been received.

A refraction is is documented in 3 sections: a Sph, Cyl and Axis. The SPH may be a positive or negative value (always indicated with a preceding +/-) that will typically be written as ##.## or #.##. The cyl value may again be positive or negative (always with a preceding +/-) and again in the same ##.##/#.## format). Finally an axis value which must be between 0 and 360.

Example Match Values:

```
+ 0.00 + 0.50 74
+0.00+0.50x74
+1.25 -2.20 110
+14.50 -0.00 96
```

Example Should Not Match Values:

*Common expressions used from similar machines that will output data that should not cause a match.*

```
 39.50  8.55 171
40.25  8.35 80
+ 0.50 DK 90
+ 1.25 125
+ 0.25* 109
```

Issues:

- When parsing values there could be a white space between the +/- (or not)
- There may be a number of white spaces between the last 2 sets of numbers, or some systems will output it in a #x# format.
- the 1st and 2nd number sets may be in a #.## format; or a ##.## format that may or may not include a leading 0

What I have thus far

```
[+-]+\s*([0-9]{1,2})+\.+([0-9]{1,2})+\s*[+-]\s*[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{1,2}\s*[0-9]{1,3}
```

Mine seems hopelessly complex. I also have not accounted for the x qualifier.

*Edit:Terminal Data Dump*
Why the data is different in some cases, i'm unsure, i just have sample data that appears to be different; fairly old machine.

```
.
.HARK    SEQ   2
.
.Sph    Cyl    Axis    VA
RIGHT EYEObj
.+ 0.00 + 0.50  74
.
.Reflex:  58

.LEFT EYEObj
.+ 0.50 + 0.25 109
.
.Reflex:  34
.Vertex:  12.0
PD:      56
.
.Ker   DK     MM    Axis
R   39.50   8.55   171
40.25   8.37    81

. AVG.    40.00  8.46
K  + 0.75 DK x 81

.L   39.00   8.66   177
.    39.50   8.52    87
.
. AVG.    39.25  8.59
.    K  + 0.50 DK x 87
..
```

Comment: A few questions: Is the amount of numbers fixed, are the signs on the first two numbers required, and can it start with whitespace?

Comment: You may be better off breaking this down to a succession expressions rather than attempting a one size fits all approach.

Comment: Are the bytes that are coming in from the device ASCII (or some other encoding) or something else?  How have you parsed the data to what you are trying to consume with Regex?

Comment: Is there a start and end character delimiting each data set? Must the regex pick this 3-number data set out of a larger text?

Comment: The data is read from a COM port into a buffer. The +/- is always required on the first two numbers. It some cases it starts with a whitespace; in other cases the machine starts it with a . I've attached a complete dump into the edited question.

Answer (score 0):

The following regex matches the sample patterns you've given, however I think you'd be better of breaking the pattern matching down to 3 expressions rather than a monolith if for anything else to mitigate the effects of a new pattern being added from a new system.

```
[+-]{1}\s{0,1}[0-9.]+\s{0,1}[+-]{1}\s{0,1}[0-9.]+[\sx]{0,1}[0-9]+
```

Here's a [something you can fiddle with](http://regexr.com/3dj60).

Comment: this won't work, as the last no. can only be between 0 and 360. in your case, it can be any number

Comment: Yes I missed the 0-360 constraint, close but no cigar!

Answer (score 0):

The condition, that the last number can be between 0 and 360, was tricky :)

Anyway, I tested your test cases, and this seems to work: `^[+-]\s*[\d]{1,2}\.[\d]{2}\s*[+-]\s*[\d]{1,2}\.[\d]{2}(?:x|\s*)(?:[\d]|[1-9][\d]|[1-2][\d][\d]|3[0-5][\d]|360)$`

Working example here: https://regex101.com/r/mH3zQ0/2

Comment: For what it's worth, I can't get this expression to work with javascript regex unless adding {1,3} to the end of the expression (prior to $) and setting the multi-line flag enabled.

Answer (score 0):

This matched all of your desired items and none of your undesired items. Give it a try:

```
"[\+\-]\s*\d+\.\d+\s*[\+\-]\s*\d+\.\d+[\sx]+(\d{1,2}|[12]\d\d|3[012345]\d|360)\b"
```

Answer (score 0):

The following regex correctly matches all of your test cases. It is presented it in free-spacing format with lots of comments so that it is self-documenting:

```cs
if (Regex.IsMatch(subjectString, 
    @"(?#!cs ophthalmology_refraction 20160608_0800)
    # SPH, CYL and AXIS Ophthalmology Refraction - e.g. +0.00+0.50x74
    ^            # Anchor to start of line.
    [ \t]*       # Optional whitespace (ws) before SPH sign.
    [+\-]        # Required sign for SPH.
    [ \t]*       # Optional ws before SPH value.
    \d{1,2}      # SPH value integer part.
    \.           # Required SPH decimal point.
    \d{2}        # SPH value fractional part has 2 digits.
    [ \t]*       # Optional whitespace (ws) before CYL sign.
    [+\-]        # Required sign for CYL.
    [ \t]*       # Optional ws before CYL value.
    \d{1,2}      # CYL value integer part.
    \.           # Required CYL decimal point.
    \d{2}        # CYL value fractional part has 2 digits.
    (?:          # Separator between CYL and AXIS - either space or x.
      [ \t]+     # Either one or more ws,
    | [Xx]       # Or an upper or lowercase X.
    )            # End separator between CYL and AXIS.
    (?:          # AXIS value is an integer from 0 to 360.
      360        # Either 360.
    | 3[0-5]\d   # Or 300-359.
    | [1-2]\d\d  # Or  100-299.
    | \d\d?      # Or 0-99.
    )            # End AXIS value.
    [ \t]*       # Optional ws after AXIS value.
    $            # Anchor to end of line.", 
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace | RegexOptions.Multiline)) {
    // Successful match
} else {
    // Match attempt failed
}
```

Note that The original question does not clearly define the context where these values appear. This solution assumes that each three-value data set occurs on one line and that the allowable whitespace between values may be spaces or tabs.

Comment: Thanks; Will test. Would removing the initial ^ allow it to search for a match anywhere? All my test data shows it starting with a whitespace, or a period.

Comment: If you remove the initial `^` anchor (and the `$` anchor at the end), then, yes it may correctly find a data set from a longer line of text. But doing so might possibly result in false positives and/or erroneous matches Additional detailed and precise information as to the actual text that you are applying the regex to would be helpful.